# Mongoose - add method to object that is returned in the callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, methods, mongoose, schema

Is there a way to add functions to the object that is returned in the callback?

```
User.find({'age':'20'}, function(err, users){
    users.function();
});
```

It seems `statics` only work on the model. Schematically :

```
User.static();
```

and `methods` only work on instances

```
(new User()).method();
```

None of them seem to work on users, which i think is just a normal js Object variable. Am I missing something ?

Comment: `users` is an array with `find`, not a single doc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`Schema.method`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-method) description, from the docs:

> Adds an instance method to documents constructed from Models compiled from this schema.

So, if you do something like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    age: Number
});

userSchema.method('showAge', function () {
    return this.age;
});
```

, and call your method in a document returned from a query like:

```
User.findOne({'age':'20'}, function(err, user){
    console.log(user.showAge());
});
```

it should work. Maybe you're having problems because you're calling your method `users.function()` in an `array`. Remember: the `find` method returns an array of documents.